# Taking a File Argument and Moving to That Directory?

Tags: directory, cd-command

Is there a Unix command or shell script that takes a file argument and moves to the containing directory, ignoring the file part of the argument altogether?

Comment: `moves` - do you mean `changes to` as in `cd`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: This must be done by the shell, not an external program, so which shell are you using? `bash` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function, like this:

```bsh
cd_to_file_location() {                          
    location=$(dirname -- "$1")
    cd -- "$location"
}

# test it out
$ mkdir /tmp/foodir
$ touch /tmp/foodir/a
$ cd_to_file_location /tmp/foodir/a 
$ pwd
/tmp/foodir
```

Comment: Double-quote your `$1`, otherwise it will fail on paths containing spaces

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for?

```
cd "${dirname "$1"}"
```

You can use `pushd` instead of `cd` as well depending on your needs.

Comment: `$0` is the path to the shell (e.g. `/bin/bash`), not the first argument.

Comment: Was sleepy yesterday, you're quite right.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
cdparent() cd -- $1:h
```

Will define a `cdparent` function that changes the current working directory to the directory part (`h`ead) of the first argument.

You can also do:

```
cd some/file(:h)
```

Where `:h` here is used in a glob qualifier again to retrieve the head of the given file.

The `:h` modifier comes from csh in the 70s where it could be applied to parameter expansion and history substitution. In `zsh`, it can be applied to those plus glob qualifiers. In `bash`, it can only be applied to history substitution. Some of those modifiers (including `:h`) are also available in `vim`, where you can do `:cd %:h` to chdir into the directory of the currently edited file for instance.

(the *parent* wording above can be a bit misleading in the case of `cdparent ..` for instance, which will do a `cd .` and not a `cd ../..` as *parent* could suggest).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that will check if a destination path is a
directory and if it's not it will get the directory name from the path
and cd to it. For example:

```
mycd()
{
    if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]
    then
        printf "Usage: mycd <PATH>\n" >&2
        return
    fi

    if [ ! -d "$1" ]
    then
        dest="$(dirname -- "$1")"
        set -- "$dest"
    fi

    cd -- "$1"
}
```

It's versatile enough to work with both directories and file paths
and as it uses real `cd` you can always go back to the previous
directory with `cd -`:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test-dir/
$ touch /tmp/test-dir/FILE
$ mycd /tmp/test-dir/FILE
$ pwd
/tmp/test-dir
$ mycd /tmp/
$ pwd
/tmp
$ cd -
/tmp/test-dir
$ pwd
/tmp/test-dir
```